# How to get User Emoney Mangopay

Tags: payment, php-7, laravel-5.7, mangopay

How to get User Emoney Mangopay, I follow the document but nothing found code sample for how to retrieve user EMoney from Mangopay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting user e-money from mangopay.

```
$this->api->Users->GetEMoney($UserId);
```